# Does the German federal agency Max Rubner Institute acting illegaly by the German Open Data law?

Tags: food, governmental-liability, database

The German federal agency *[Max Rubner-Institut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Rubner-Institut)* (MRI) deals with food quality control and related consumer protection.

From their studies, they have created and maintain the national food registry *Bundeslebensmittelschlüssel* (BLS) similar to the *[FoodData Central](https://data.nal.usda.gov/dataset/fooddata-central)* provided by the USDA.

While access to FoodData Central is free of charge, the German BLS is under a [license with costs](https://www.blsdb.de/license) even for private persons, with a quite expensive server license.

On the other hand, there has been a so-called "Open Data law", [EGovG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/egovg/) which requires that federal agencies provide electronic public access to their data.

Ironically, your have to *print out* the order form for the BLS and after you have paid you can download the data.

Now, is it legal in terms of the mentioned German Open Data law that MRI charges usage of BLS?

Comment: I think your implied interpreation of the EgovG 'all government data should be available online to anyone for free' is not quite what the law actually says.

Comment: this is what I'm trying to understand what's open data by this law.

Comment: Not familiar with this area of law so just a comment, but according to the very first sentence in EGovG, the law applies only to **administrative** activities, I'm not of the opinion this qualifies.